# Flutter Firebase Play_Integrity_Token invalid app info

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

Firstly I am trying to achieve sms login in my app.
I get this error when I try to send sms to user .

Explanation: My app was working a month ago but after uploading it to google play console my app got broken I don't know why or how but app asked me to add AppCheck , play integrity etc. I added all of them and now it gives me this error:

> I/flutter (30956): This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid app info in play_integrity_token ]

I checked every sha key in both firebase console and google cloud console.
Tested in real devices to see if problem is about emulator but real devices (android) did not work either. App check is tested in both debug and playIntegrity modes.
I checked AppCheck in firebase and it shows my attempts in authentication were authorized however error says otherwise . AppCheck is enforced.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I updated my emulator's **Google Play Services Version** then it was working as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use pervious version of com.google.firebase:firebase-auth

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).